# How do you make a list of lists in python3?

Tags: python, list, insert, python-3.5

So, currently I've created 2 empty `list`, with length 128 and 64, added numbers into them (just to test it out) and now I'm trying to insert the `DirectoryEntries` `list` into the `AvailableBlocks` `list`. But when I print the new list out, it just prints `None`. Is there a way to do this while keeping `DirectoryEntries` a `list`?

```
AvailableBlocks = list() * 128
DirectoryEntries = list() * 64
AvailableBlocks.append(1)
AvailableBlocks.append(2)
print(AvailableBlocks)
DirectoryEntries.append(123)
DirectoryEntries.append(456)
print(DirectoryEntries)
print(AvailableBlocks.insert(0, DirectoryEntries))
```

Comment: I think you should `print(AvailableBlocks)` immediately after creating it and see if it is what you expect it to be.  I suspect not. (An "empty list with length 128" doesn't really make sense.)

Comment: I've tried both insert() and append() and both print the same result.

Comment: I mean take a look at `list() * 128`.  You'll see that it is `[]`.

Comment: OK, it's just an empty list to begin with. I thought that if you multiplied it by something then that's how many elements you could fit in it.

Comment: It is basically the same as `[] + [] + [] + ... + []`, which is the concatenation of 128 empty lists,  resulting in an empty list.

Comment: I think we posted that at the same time.

So, why, after I add elements, does it print 'None' when I try to put DirectoryEntries into AvailableBlocks?

Comment: See the answers.  By the way, I'm 99.99 percent sure this question is a duplicate.  Many folks get tripped up by the fact that `insert` operates *in place* and returns `None`.

Comment: Even when I comment out the 128 and 64 it still prints none

Comment: This it literally the first time I've asked this question

Comment: I've tried it with append too and it prints the same result...

Comment: I don't mean *you* asked it before.  I mean lots of other Python programmers have asked it (well, something close to it) before here on stackoverflow. `insert`, `append` and `extend` modify the list *in place*, and return `None`.

Answer (score 4):

The insert does not return a value.
Try

```
AvailableBlocks.insert(0, DirectoryEntries)
print(AvailableBlocks)
```

and it should work